# Converting ASCII values to characters in Java

Tags: java, ascii

I am currently working on an assignment where I have to decrypt a secret phrase, but run and print 100 different possibilities based on what the ASCII value is. I have gotten this far and believe that what I have should work, but when I run the program it doesn't print anything, just says that the build is successful. Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String phrase = ":mmZ\\dxZmx]Zpgy";
    int value;
    for (int key = 1; key >= 100; key++){
        for (int i = 0; i > 15; i++ ){
           int ascii = (int) phrase.charAt(i);
           if(ascii + key > 126){
                value = ((ascii + key) - 127) + 32;
                System.out.print((char)value);
           }
           else{
               value = (ascii + key);
               System.out.print((char)value);
           }
```

Thanks, any bit of information helps with this.

Comment: Your loops are never entered. `>=` is the `key` test. You want `<=` (presumable). And `i < 15` in the inner loop.

Comment: You seem to think the condition in the `for` loop is when to stop. It's not. It's when to keep looping.

Comment: `int key = 1; key >= 100` 1 is never greater than 100, so your loop is never entered.

Comment: Sorry @ElliottFrisch I didn't see that comment before I posted.

Comment: @Andreas Should I? There's 2 other people that have posted the exact same thing.

Comment: Also 2 answers that say literally the exact same thing.

Comment: @Andreas Ok, that makes sense, I'll do that from now on.

Comment: @TheMCProgrammer If they want to. You seemed to want to, otherwise why say "sorry", and since you seemed fairly new (low rep), I thought I'd help you by showing what you could do about that. It's up to you, and I'm now deleting my comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int key = 1; key >= 100; key++)
```

The for loop initializes `key` to 1, and then checks if `key` is greater than or equal to 100, which it isn't, so the loop immediately terminates.

Similarly, `for (int i = 0; i > 15; i++ )` is checking if `i` is greater than 15 when it has just been initialized to 0.

Comment: Thank you so much, I never would've noticed that!